# How do i add Bootstrap css and js file in my project from webpack in reactjs and what do i add in webpack config file?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack

I am new to react and i have a project in which i  am using bootstrap for css but now i want to load that css and js file from webpack.. I don't know how to load bootstrap files from webpack and how to write the config file of webpack but then also i have tried to load by searching about it..
here is my config file

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
entry: './index.js',
output: { filename: 'bundle.js' },
module: {
loaders: [
  {
    test: /.jsx?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    query: {
      presets: ['es2015', 'react']
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
  },
 ]
},
};
```

Please tell me any solution how do i do that?
Thanks a lot in advance.

And what do i import in my index.js file?
i just have my routes there..

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
ReactDOM.render(
   routes ,
  document.getElementById("crm")
);
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@victorleungtw/how-to-use-webpack-with-react-and-bootstrap-b94d33765970#.opq4nd3q0

Answer (score 0):

This is one option using Webpack 2 and HtmlWebpackPlugin / ExtractTextPlugin.

Add `import './style.css';` (or wherever they are) to your react index.js (Where it says style you could also put bootstrap.min.css and/or other files.

Same for the js files `import './jquery.js';` and `import './bootstrap.js';`.

The stylesheet Link/href will be injected in your index.html and the output css file(s) put in the dist (`output.path`) dir. The js files will be injected in your bundle.js  (check `CommonsChunkPlugin` ([link](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/)) to output these and other files in separate .js files.

`output.publicPatch` is important to make it not only work when index.html is requested directly but also via a route. This makes sure the link to css is added as /style.css not just style.css in index.html.

webpack.config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');

const config = {
    entry: {
        bundle: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/', <- used by HtmlWebpackPlugin
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use: 'babel-loader',
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/ 
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: "css-loader"
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.html'
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
    ]    
}

module.exports = config;
```

Hope this helps. Let me know.

Comment: Did you change to using webpack 2? Did you import the js/css files in react component?